# Highlight Dates in Rich:calendar

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces

I have a calendar which is working fine. it displays records on click and changes the colour to green or red. if records are available date will become red colored. 
I don't want onclick I want calendar to displays date colours on
calendars onload event.** KIndly help. following is my code . I think problem with css, I guess

```
.postive-records .rf-cal-sel { 
    background-color: green; 
} 

.no-records .rf-cal-sel { 
    background-color: red; 
} 

<rich:calendar styleClass="#{eventMaster.eventMasterList!=null and eventMaster.eventMasterList.size()>0?'postive-records':'no-records'}" locale="EN" 
      id="searchDateCalendarcommon" popup="false" 
      showApplyButton="false" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy" 
      value="#{eventMaster.eventSearchDate}" > 
    <rich:tooltip followMouse="false" 
          showDelay="100" 
          direction="topRight" 
          layout="block" 
          onmouseover=""> 
        <h:outputText value="#{eventMaster.calendarTooltipText}"
              style="color: red;font-size: 12px;"/> 
    </rich:tooltip> 
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{commonOutputContentBean.showEvents()}" 
          render="cmnoplayoutfrm searchDateCalendarcommon" />
</rich:calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

The calendar simply displays days in a month, it isn't linked to any data. Furthermore styleClass is applied to the entire calendar not to the cells. You need to provide a dataModel.

The datamodel has to implement `org.richfaces.model.CalendarDataModel`, and you also need to implement `org.richfaces.model.CalendarDataModelItem` for the days which is a plain object with getters and setters. The CalendarModel would be something like this:

```
public class MyCalendarModel implements CalendarDataModel {

    private boolean hasEvents(Calendar calendar) {
        // …
    }

    @Override
    public CalendarDataModelItem[] getData(Date[] dateArray) {
        CalendarDataModelItem[] modelItems = new MyCalendarModelItem[dateArray.length];
        Calendar current = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        Calendar today = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        today.setTime(new Date());
        CalendarModelItem modelItem;
        for (int i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
            current.setTime(dateArray[i]);
            modelItem = new MyCalendarModelItem();
            if (hasEvents(current)) {
                modelItem.setStyleClass("postive-records");
            } else {
                modelItem.setStyleClass("no-records");
            }
            modelItems[i] = modelItem;
        }
        return modelItems;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getToolTip(Date date) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can check the example in the [showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=calendar&sample=dataModel).

Comment: Thank you. I have made changes in code but still not found solution

Comment: Is there any problem with my hasEvent method..    private boolean hasEvents(Calendar calendar) {
        return true;      
    }

Comment: Well no, are you not getting the css classes in there? Mind you `.postive-records .rf-cal-sel` will not work, your classes are getting applied to the table cells.

Comment: What code need to write at  private boolean hasEvents(Calendar calendar) {
        // …
    }